# How to import custom python modules with ROS?

Tags: python, ros, catkin

In side simulator.py, I'd imported PID.py from Control which is valid according to PyCharm IDE.

Program Structure:

```
src
├── quantum_drone
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Control
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── Keys.py
│   │   ├── MonotonicTime.py
│   │   └── PID.py
│   ├── package.xml
│   └── scripts
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── simulator.py
```

I realized I didn't have setup.py setup in my root directory (quantum_drone), so I when and set it up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup
   
# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
     packages=['quantum_drone'],
     scripts=['Control', 'scripts'],
     package_dir={'': 'src'},
 )
 
setup(**setup_args)
```

In my CMakeLists.txt, I had uncommented the catkin_python_setup() and inside catkin_install_python I wrote:

```
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
   scripts/simulator.py
   Control/PID.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Finally, I ran:

```
catkin_make 
source devel/setup.bash
```

I try to run:
`rosrun quantum_drone simulator.py`

But I keep getting this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kannachan/drone/src/quantum_drone/scripts/simulator.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Control import PID
ImportError: No module named Control
```

I could've swore I did everything I needed to do, so I'm not sure where I when wrong such that I couldn't import my files/directories.

Contents of PID.py (I can import MonotonicTime.py just fine):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pymavlink import mavutil
from MonotonicTime import monotonic_time
import numpy as np

current_time = monotonic_time


class PID:

    def __init__(self, vehicle, kp=0, ki=0, kd=0, velocity=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.kp = kp  # Constants (kp, ki, kd)
        self.ki = ki
        self.kd = kd
        self.drone = vehicle
        self.p_terms = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)  # 3-axis
        self.i_terms = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
        self.d_terms = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
        self.velocity = np.asarray(velocity)  # Desired Velocity
        self.current_velocity = np.array(self.drone.velocity)  # Current Velocity
        self.errors = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)  # Previous Error
        self.time = current_time()  # Current Time
        self.__max__ = 40  # Max Speed
        self.__min__ = 0  # Min Speed

    def reset(self):
        #  Resetting terms
        self.p_terms = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
        self.i_terms = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
        self.d_terms = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
        self.errors = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=float)

    def calculate_change(self):
        now = current_time()
        delta_error = self.velocity - self.current_velocity  # Change in error
        delta_time = now - self.time if now - self.time else 1e-16  # Change in time
        self.time = now
        return delta_error, delta_time

    def pid_calculation(self):
        delta_error, delta_time = self.calculate_change()
        # PID controller formula
        self.p_terms = delta_error * self.kp
        self.i_terms += self.errors * delta_time
        self.d_terms = (delta_error - self.errors) / delta_time
        self.errors = delta_error
        outputs = self.kp * self.p_terms + self.ki * self.i_terms + self.kd * self.d_terms
        outputs = np.where(outputs > self.__max__, self.__max__, outputs)  # Replacing terms too big
        outputs = np.where(outputs < self.__min__, self.__min__, outputs)  # Replacing terms too small
        return outputs

    def send_command(self):
        vx, vy, vz = self.pid_calculation()
        msg = self.drone.message_factory.set_position_target_location_ned_encode(
            0,
            0, 0,
            mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_BODY_NED,
            0b0000111111000111,
            0, 0, 0,
            vx, vy, vz,
            0, 0
        )
        self.drone.send_mavlink(msg)
        self.drone.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your import is wrong. It should be importing from PID not Control. As well, within ROS1 you don’t need a setup.py file for a Python package.

Comment: Not sure if i read it correctly, but i changed `from Control import PID` to `from Control.PID import PID`. This still gave me the same error or did I misinterpreted your answer?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear, I meant you shouldn’t be trying to import from `Control` because when catkin installs the package there is no Control folder. You need `from PID import <classname>`

Comment: I can't import PID directly from Control directory, so I had to add `file:///home/kannachan/drone/src/quantum_drone/Control` into the path. I tried `from PID import PID` and run `rosrun quantum_drone simulator.py` and it giving me a similar error that it can not find the module.

Comment: Please edit your post with the contents of PID.py. You also should not add the the package source to your search path.

Comment: I'd just updated the post with the content of PID.py. PID.py and MonotonicTime.py are in the same directory called Control and I can import them just fine. However, when i tried to import PID.py from within the directory called scripts, it will come with an error, so I am wondering if the program structure is the issue here. Just to make sure, did I do catkin_install_python correctly?

Comment: Something else is going on then. Did you try to import `PID` or `PID.py`? Your `catkin_install_python` is also correct. All this does is put all the python files in the same `build/lib/package_name` dir. So, this means for the above code `from PID import PID` is correct. I suspect you have another package named PID somewhere. As well since this is ROS there is already a pid package I'd suggest looking into.

Comment: I decided to move the entire Control directory inside the scripts directory and ran `rosrun quantum_drone simulator.py` and inside simulator.py I'd imported PID by doing `from Control.PID import PID` which you told me not to do, but I'm not how else to get it to work because of my ignorance. This time it work just fine, but I'll give an update whether this problem continues to persist. Appreciate your help!